# jQuery - reproduce serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization

I have multiple div elements and each one has a set of form fields (text inputs and selects).

Instead of the `name` attribute these fields have a `rel` attribute that has the same value as "name" should have.

How can I reproduce the behaviour of jQuery's serialize (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on these fields?

the HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" rel="title" value="bla" />
  <input type="text" rel="count" value="5" />
  <select rel="page">
    <option value="home">home</option>
    <option value="about" selected="selected">about</option>
    <option value="404">404</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="serialize_above_fields[]" value="" />
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" rel="title" value="bla" />
  <input type="text" rel="count" value="5" />
  <select rel="page">
    <option value="home">home</option>
    <option value="about" selected="selected">about</option>
    <option value="404">404</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="serialize_above_fields[]" value="" />
</div>

...
```

basically I want to produce a hidden input field with all the values of fields within the div it resides (and use rel's as keys), like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="serialize_above_fields[]" value="title=bla&count=5&page=check2&page=about" />
```

Comment: Is giving them a `name` attribute for a short moment an option?

Comment: if by adding a name I wouldn't get them in $_GET, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `map` utility to do that pretty easily.

```
$('div').each(function() {
  var serializedData = $(this).find(':text, select').map(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).attr('rel') + '=' + $(el).val();
  }).get();

  $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val(serializedData.join('&'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input elements are all within a `<form></form>`, You could try to serialize your form using something like this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.rel]) {
            if (!o[this.rel].push) {
                o[this.rel] = [o[this.rel]];
            }
            o[this.rel].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.rel] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Comment: but I cant wrap them inside `form`, because I already have a form containing all the above html

Comment: Then maybe put them in a div, and serialize the div? Not 100% sure it'll work - but this is what I was using to serialize before jQuery.